# Write permission inside a folder but not on this folder

Tags: linux, permissions

Given this directory structure:

```
/parent
    /a
    /b
```

Can I prevent the "parent" folder to be removed/renamed/changed permissions by any user other than root, while the user "bob" could freely add/delete/edit files and folders inside it? Like removing "a", renaming "b", creating "c"... but nothing on "parent".

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You'll utilize [**`chmod`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod) and [**`chown`**](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) to accomplish this:

```bash
# Nested Files and Directories #
  chown -R bob:bob /parent/*
  chmod -R 760 /parent/*

# Parent Directory #
  chown root:root /parent
  chmod 750 /parent
```

Comment: After I ran these commands, bob cannot cd to /parent anymore. Which is normal as he cannot execute it. I need bob to be able to cd to /parent, as well as create/delete directories and files in /parent. Just, he shouldn't be able to edit /parent itself

Comment: @Ninj I can't boot up a VM at the moment to test, but you should be able to play around with the permissions of `/parent` to get the desired access.  Try `chmod 755 /parent`.  Let me know if that works and I'll update my answer =]

Comment: I tried `chown root:bob` (because bob is in the "bob" group): it can cd, but cannot mkdir. I tried `chmod 755`: same result. I think that a user can mkdir only if the current directory gives him write access. But I don't want that because I don't want the user to delete /parent

Comment: @Ninj The only workaround I've found thus far is to created an additional nesting within `/parent` (i.e. `/parent/1/a`, `/parent/1/b`, etc.) and have `bob` work out of the nested folder `/parent/1`.  If this is an acceptable solution, I'll edit my answer accordingly.